# Flutter, the second animation controller is not animating, why?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have two animation controllers using **TickerProviderStateMixin** the first animation is working smoothly while the second does not animate when I trigger it's **forward** method : Here are their declarations :

```
class HomeAnimator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeAnimatorState createState() => _HomeAnimatorState();
}

class _HomeAnimatorState extends State<HomeAnimator>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  AnimationController _signupctrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 900), vsync: this);
    _signupctrl =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 900), vsync: this);
    // _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
    _signupctrl.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dahome(controllers: [_controller,_signupctrl]);
  }
}
```

I have two files for the different set of animations :

-- Mahome_EnterAnimation: when clicked on sign-in button 
here's a relevant piece :

```
class EntAnime {
  EntAnime(this.controller)
      : opanime = Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
          parent: controller,
          curve: Interval(0, 0.5, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
        )),
        r_opanime = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(CurvedAnimation(
          parent: controller,
          curve: Interval(0, 0.5, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
        )),
        hfact = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(CurvedAnimation(
          parent: controller,
          curve: Interval(0, 0.5, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
        )),
```

-- Mahome_SignupAnime: for when I press sign-up button

```
class SignupAnime {
  SignupAnime(this.controller):
  qopanime = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(CurvedAnimation(
          parent: controller,
          curve: Interval(0.0, 0.5, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
        )),
        qhfact = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(CurvedAnimation(
          parent: controller,
          curve: Interval(0.5, 0.9, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
        ));

  final AnimationController controller;
  final Animation<double> qopanime;
  final Animation<double> qhfact;
}
```

This is how I declared it :

```
class Dahome extends StatefulWidget {
  Dahome({Key key, this.title, @required List<AnimationController> controllers})
      : daanime = EntAnime(controllers[0]),
        signanime = SignupAnime(controllers[1]),
        super(key: key);
  final EntAnime daanime;
  final SignupAnime signanime;
  final String title;
  Dastate createState() => Dastate(daanime, signanime);
  // @override
}

class Dastate extends State<Dahome> {
  Dastate(this.maanime, this.loganime);
  final EntAnime maanime;
  final SignupAnime loganime; 
...
```

I called the forward methods in two different buttons:

The first one here and the second the same way:

```
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () => {
       maanime.controller.forward()
       },
```

Comment: there is no `forward()` method called in your code, also how do you create `EntAnime` and `SignupAnime` objects?

Comment: and where is `loganime.controller.forward()`?

Comment: I wrote it just the same way, by the way thanks lots for lending me some time cousin.

Comment: dont use this: `Dastate(this.maanime, this.loganime)` instead remove `final EntAnime maanime;
  final SignupAnime loganime;` fields and that constructor from `Dastate` and use `widget.daanime` and `widget.signanime` from `Dastate` class

Comment: Just done it, the second controller (set of animations) is still not animating when I press the button it doesn't animate but when I hit r in the flutter console it gets straight to the final value without animation. (Nice tip though, code is  much prettier now)

Comment: i dont get it: `r` is for hot reload - i mean it is used when you do any changes in your code so what does it have to do with animations?

Comment: I mean if I press the button for the 2nd controllers forward method, nothing visible happens, but when I press r the changes I wish happen but there is no transition

Comment: Oh the problem was the animatedbuilder widget I had to change the animation parameter with the second controller, thank you cousin I really appreciated that pastebin did more than 15 videos on youtube ! btw hello from mauritania 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, the problem was the `animatedbuilder` widget I had to change the `animation` parameter with the second controller